# Record Video in Background

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have an application in which I want to record the video in background. The main steps of the process are:

1. When the app starts, a `play` icon is displayed.
2. On clicking the icon, video recording should start. User should NOT have to press the red record start button of the native camera application. The app needs to display that recording. After 10 seconds, the recording should stop automatically and save the video directly.
3. If the user switches between the application, the video recording should continue recording even in background.

I would be glad if at least the step 2 of the process is solved. I did look into `backgroundvideo` plugin [here.](https://github.com/jamesla/backgroundvideo) But it did not help. Also, I tried with `media-capture` but I have to press the record and stop button.

Comment: found any solutions?